# OpenAI Gym CarRacing

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines, racing

I want to create a reinforcement learning model using stable-baselines3 PPO that can drive OpenAI Gym Car racing environment and I have been having a lot of errors and package compatibility issues.
I have currently this code just for random actions

```
import gym 
from stable_baselines3 import PPO

environment_name = "CarRacing-v0"
env = gym.make(environment_name)

episodes = 5
for episode in range(1, episodes+1):
    state = env.reset()
    done = False
    score = 0 
    
    while not done:
        env.render()
        action = env.action_space.sample()
        n_state, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
        score+=reward
    print('Episode:{} Score:{}'.format(episode, score))
env.close()
```

Runnning on Ubuntu 20.04, in VSCode Jupyter notebook. With these packages in a conda env
[image]

Even with random actions I am currently getting an error on `state = env.reset()`
[image]

I tried different versions of gym and other packages and none seem to work flawlessly. Could anyone please help me, my only requirement is to make it work (firstly random and then with PPO) no matter what versions of packages.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hello there seems like environment has error

change `environment_name = "CarRacing-v0"` to as `environment_name = "CarRacing-v2"`
it might fix erorr

and if doesnt work
uninstall and install again

```
pip uninstall stable-baselines3[extra]
```

or

```
pip uninstall stable-baselines3
```

after you uninstall it install it again

```
pip install stable-baselines3[extra]
```

and remember,

you need to install **Pytorch** if you didn't it might be the problem
https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/

(Sorry for late answer)